# I can't extract sealed bearings out of the wheel

Tags: hub, rear-wheel, bearings, giant

I face the problem [again](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/59006/i-cant-extract-sealed-bearings-out-of-hub) of extracting the bearings, this time out of the wheel of my Giant XTC Advanced 29” 1.5 2017, Giant wheel system, hub OEM manufactured by Formula.

Once removed caps and cones the axle can be released freely (no hit, no pressure, all loose) and bearings appear uncovered at both sides but I can't use the axle to extract the bearings. Then I hit hard with the punch from inside out but they do not move a milimeter. I have a *déjà vu* and stop hitting.

Again: What am I missing?

UPDATE: Last picture. It seems to me, but not sure, that the box of the axle is here wider than the bearing and maybe there is a ring preventing the bearing to be extracted that side. Maybe a circlip again? Or anyway should both bearings be extracted by the disc side? Sounds weird, I'm just pondering.

[image: bearing disc side]
[image: bearing pawls side]
[image: bearing pawls side closer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bearings are out! After cleaning and inspecting I realized my guess in the UPDATE was baseless. Again the punch didn't work, but feeling confident I tried with the thru axle and the bearings jumped. The question is now: **Which is the *orthodox* and/or convenient way of extracting the bearings in this type of assembly? What is the best tool to use to hit the bearings from inside out?** At first time I was reluctant to use the axle to avoid damaging the sealing of the bearing (which finally happened), considering my intention is to reuse them.